# Can CiviCRM entities be used as events to trigger Drupal Rules?

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-rules

I have CiviCRM Entity installed, Drupal Rules, up to date versions of both.

I'm just creating a simple rule that says when a CiviRM Contribution Page is viewed, a "Hello World" message is displayed.

Getting nowhere with it. It does not even trigger Rules at all, so no debug, no log entries.

Works fine with Drupal content.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule will only trigger when the Drupal version of the contribution page at path /civicrm-contribution-page/(id)

We haven't added a feature to trigger the rule event when the civi version of the contribution page is viewed.

Comment: Woo. In all my years I did not know that you could have Drupal versions of contribution pages. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ah I see where this is coming from, CiviCRM Entity. What I actually want to trigger a rule when the user visits the transaction page for the contribution, rather than the contribution page itself. So, for example, if someone visits a contribution transcation page for member renewal, I can check whether they have filled in data elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm doing it is to use Path Rules module to check the CiviCRM URL for the transact page. 
So we look for the path say /civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1

That triggers the rule. We then fetch the CiviCRM contact entity for the current user.

The Contact entity has all of the custom data in it.

We pass that to a rule component that evaluates a custom field value and does an action as appropriate.

So this rule could be used in a situation where a user has to complete a complex professional registration procedure using Webform CiviCRM, where a profile is not appropriate. Upon completion they are directed to a membership renewal page.

If they try to access the renewal page first, without having made the declaration they are redirected back to the webform.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for posting your solution. Adding Path Rules to the toolbox!